# Save to user info on Pusher Presence channels

Tags: pusher

The user object in Pusher presence channels is initiated from the auth callback. This object is persisted and contains user info.

But how can you update this user info and have it keep that persistent state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can you update this user info and have it keep that persistent state?

Unfortunately you can't.

The only way to change this information is to unsubscribe the user from the channel and resubscribe. Upon re-subscription you can authenticate with the changed data.

Comment: Alright. That's too bad. I guess I have to save that data locally then and query it from the user ID. Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit crap of Pusher, but Googling around it and picking through the Pusher docs it seems to be accurate (plus we can probably take Mr Leggetter's word for it, as he's a former Pusher employee). Frustrating, but nothing we can do about it.